# How to play Starcraft 2 on LAN?

Tags: starcraft-2

Every now and then I go out of town with family for a weekend or what-not.  On these trips my brother and I always bring our laptops & such and we are always wanting to play 1v1 against each other or 2v2 with bots on LAN.

There is no internet connection aside from our dinky little mobile hotspot which we pay for data usage.  It's not an option.

How can he and I play Starcraft 2 on an Ad-hoc network we set up?

Comment: You can't (officially). You must be connected to Blizzard's servers to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starcraft 2 cannot be played on LAN.

Comment: I wasn't asking about Diablo 3, that was an off-topic aside.  And apparently there are workarounds for playing Starcraft 2 offline.  That's what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Mkalafut There might be, but they're unofficial and often used for illegal copies of the game. Because of this, we can't help you find them.

Comment: Fair enough.  Pretty lame, especially since we both own our own retail copies of the game but hey what can you do I guess.

Comment: Yeah he made the same edit to mine too.

Comment: The fact that you own retail copies of the game don't matter. Unfortunately, we can't help you find "work-arounds" for things that violate ToS with the game. SC2 is specifically designed to work through Battle.net 2.0 and doesn't allow anything else.